# Efficient data structure that returns smallest element greater or equal than given key and allows decrease key

Tags: data-structures

Is there an efficient (log n) data structure that allows the following operations:

- Return the smallest element that is greater or equal to a given key
- Exchange this element with a smaller one and rearrange the structure accordingly

The number of elements is known and will not change during lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [balanced binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) like a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)

A Red-Black tree has O(log(n)) time complexity for search, insertion and deletion.

You will have to make some modification to return the smallest element that is greater or equal to a given key. But the basic behavior is provided by this data structure I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As it is answered you could implement a binary search tree. This code may help.

1. First you have to find the node in the tree

   ```
    private Node<Key, Value> find (Node<Key, Value> node, Key key){
        if (node == null) return null;

        int comp = comparator.compare(key, node.key);

        if (comp < 0) return find(node.left, key);
        else if(comp > 0) return find(node.right, key);
        else return node;
    }
   ```
2. Now that we have the node, we should find the smallest key but bigger or equal than the node's key, this mean that if the node has a right node this will be a bigger key, but if the right node is null, we must return the node key.

   ```
    private Node<Key, Value> min(Node<Key, Value> node){
        if (node.left == null) return node;
        else return min(node.left);
    }

    public Key ceiling(Key key){ 
        Node<Key, Value> node = find(root, key);
        if (node.right == null) return node.key;
        return min(node.right).key;
    }
   ```

The second item you ask occur when you remove a node which has to children, so it goes to its smaller child of his right child and insert it in his position.

```
    private Node<Key, Value> remove(Node<Key, Value> node, Key key){
        if (node == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        int comp = comparator.compare(key, node.key);

        if (comp > 0) node.right = remove(node.right, key);
        else if (comp < 0) node.left = remove(node.left, key);
        else{ //Found the node to remove

            if (node.right == null) return node.left; //Does not have right child. (if even does not have left child return null)
            else if (node.left == null) return node.right; //Does not have left child.
            else{ //Has right and left children

                Node<Key, Value> lower = min(node.right); //The lower node of its right child node
                node.key = lower.key;
                node.value = lower.value;
                remove(node.right, lower.key); //Remove the lower node that remains in the tree
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```